# The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server

Tags: mysql, mule

This project was successfully deployed in studio. But when I deploy in cloudhub it shows the error. I am using mysql database. Can any one solve?

```
org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.ConnectionCreationException: Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/company : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. (java.sql.SQLException) (org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.DbConnectionException).
```

Comment: The operative part of the message is not MySQL's pointless drivel about the last packet time but 'cannot get connection'. To answer which, the first question is whether the DB server is running in the localhost? On port 3306?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect to a MySQL database in your computer. That worked in Studio because you had the database running there. In the CloudHub deployment there is not, and will never be, a database running. You need to change the JDBC URL to point to a real database that is somewhere else and it is actually accessible from your CloudHub deployed application. That is something you need to resolve, not a problem with CloudHub.